Multivariable limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(\cos(x^2+y^2))}{\ln(\cos(3x^2+3y^2))}$
I came today across the following problem:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(\cos(x^2+y^2))}{\ln(\cos(3x^2+3y^2))}$$
My first thought was to substitute $$x^2 + y^2 = t$$ and solve the limit using l'Hopital.
I am not really sure whether this method is correct. Both expressions in nominator and denominator are not differentiable in some intervals. I would like to know whether this doesn't interfere with the usage of l'Hopital rule in this example.

both are differentiable around the origin, that is all you need for l'hoptial.

Well, in some intervals, the function inside the limit is not defined, but luckily, when $0<x^2+y^2<\pi/6,$ then $\cos(3x^2+3y^2)>0,$ and the numerator and denominator are defined and differentiable there.

You'll need to know $\sin(t)/\sin(3t)\to 1/3$ as $t\to0.$ This is not hard to prove.

Thank you, now I've managed to do it. This limit wasn't that hard to compute but I wasn't sure whether l'Hopital can be used here given the function not being defined in some intervals.

Yes this is a fine way, in order to obtain
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(\cos(x^2+y^2))}{\ln(\cos(3x^2+3y^2))}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos t)}{\ln(\cos 3t)}$$
and in order to avoid l'Hopital's rule we can also proceed by standard limits, for example as follows
$$\frac{\ln(\cos t)}{\ln(\cos 3t)}=\frac{\ln(1+(\cos t-1))}{\cos t -1}\frac{\cos 3t -1}{\ln(1+(\cos 3t-1))}\frac{\cos t -1}{t^2}\frac{(3t)^2}{\cos 3t -1}\;\frac19$$
